# How to get abs Mat in Android Opencv c++?

Tags: android, opencv, mat, absolute-value

I would like to get absolute matrix in Android Opencv c++ library.
I am using abs(Mat m) function but it will return MatExpr object. Do you know how to get Mat object just with absolute values of matrix?

```
    Mat * laplacian = getMat(byteArray, counter);
    MatExpr absolute = abs(*laplacian);

    Mat * absoluteMat = ????
```

I did not found any Mat constructor for this, could you help me how to retype this MatExpression? Thank you very much

**Solution:**

```
Mat * absolute = new Mat(abs(*(laplacian)));
```

Thanks for everyone, who tried to help :)

Comment: Mat absoluteMat = abs(*laplacian);

Comment: Miki, It will not return Mat object, but MatExpr.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Have you tried?

Comment: yes, it works on MS visual studio, but it does not with android NDK. But thanks for a tip anyway :)

Comment: the different behavior is bit weird, but there is a solution working for android NDK too. Thanks for your time Miki!

Answer (score 0):

It is the first function in this reference: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

> C++: MatExpr abs(const Mat& m)

Comment: I need to return Mat object, not MatExpr. I used this function in problem description